# ActiveX is not registering in Window 10, IE -11 (64 bit)

Tags: c++, windows-10, activex, internet-explorer-11, ocx

We have an ActiveX make in C++. And we distribute it to our users via the CAB and internet. It was registering fine on every browsers and OS.

But is not registering in Windows 10, IE-11 (64 bit). And not even prompting to install the ActiveX.

Same ActiveX is registering successfully in IE-11 (64 bit) Windows 7.

Comment: Control Panel > Internet Settings > Security.

Comment: @HansPassant Sir, I have tried those option but no solution.